# Typeahead in ASP.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

The first image shows that the method I created in user class.
[image]

The second image shows the controller that I created. How I take the data from GetGroupManagerAndFranchiseConsultantList? What should I need to write within view?
[image: code]

Comment: Do not post your code as an image. Post it as text. It's easier to copy/paste, it's editable, and it's searchable. We don't program with image editors.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are returning Json. So I assume you are calling this call from something like this

```
<script>
$.getJSON("/Search",function(data){
    // data is a JS OBJECT of your JSON data.
});
</script>
```

If you were looking to use MVC Views you need to return it as a view and use the built-in model binding.